# React - how to implement a "discard changes" popup that intercept every click in the application?

Tags: reactjs, popup, user-input

I would like to implement a single popup that is going to be shown every time the use try to exit the current page with some active changes.
[discard changes popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTptt.png)

I've already implemented this dynamic but I did it on every single click event that I know is going to change the page and make the user loose the data inserted.

```
 const [showDiscard, setShowDiscard] = useState(false)
    const onClickFocus = (event: any) => {
        event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation()

        if (isChanges()) {
            setShowDiscard(true) //this make the popup visible
        }
        else {
            pushNewPortfoliobutton() //this is the action to perform
        }
    }
```

I've tried to generalize this logic by adding an `addEventListener "click"` on the document and intercept the object click but as per React & Browser event lifecycle the object click is always fired before the document click and it makes it hard to intercept and block.

I would like a solution where I can intercept the click,stop the action, show the popup, make the user choose and eventually move on with the click action.